# CSS grid set span independent of track position (grid-column)

Tags: css, css-grid

As [MDN explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column), one can set the track position and track end position for a grid cell using `grid-column`, or you can specify a start and span, or a span, etc.

Now say some general layout sets that cells by default to span x number of columns (depends on size, layout etc).

Now I wish to specify a certain cell must start from column 1, but keep its same span width.

How does one indepently set the column start track position while keep the same span?

Something like `grid-column-span` (does not exist) and `grid-column-start`

Some obvious code to make @biberman happy

```css
.foo {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.bar {
    grid-column: 1;  /* this will override the span 2 property, how to keep it as span 2 but start at position one, in practice may not know what the span is. */
}
```

Comment: Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'd argue that code isn't strictly required here, since it's more of a hypothetical question about CSS, and potential means by which an element might be sized to span multiple tracks without having to first specify the track in which it should start. I can't check right now, but would `grid-column: auto / span 2` work?

Comment: Either what @DavidsaysreinstateMonica says, or just specify start and end separately. `grid-column-end: span 2` then just set and change `grid-column-start` as desired